# Preferred way to POST with params from a listing template in Django

Tags: html, django, forms

I was looking for some input on the preferred way of making a post request from a list template in Django. The way I'm currently using doesn't quite seem right to me, even though it works.

Let's say I have a table of data from my model, SomeModel, which I'm outputting in a Django GCBV ListView.

```
class SomeModelList(ListView):
    model = SomeModel
```

In my template I'm iterating over the list of models and outputting each row in a table with some of the data, and I want two buttons which make a POST to perform some operation on the current row's object.

I can write an entire form for each operation manually. Something like:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object.name }}</br>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url 'do_something' {{ object.pk }}"><input type="button" value="Do Something"/></form></br>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url 'do_something_else' {{ object.pk }}"><input type="button" value="Do Something Else"/></form></br>
{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't seem correct to be writing out these form tags like this.

Is this really the best way? Maybe I should have a single giant form around the whole list and use some properties of the button? Maybe I should be doing something with Django forms? Maybe something else entirely?

Thanks!